# Significance of return in the method with return type as void in Java

Tags: java

Code Example:

```
public class TestReturn {
    public void printNum(int[] ab){

        int i = 0;
        for( i=0; i<ab.length; i++){
        if(ab[i] < 10){
             System.out.println("less than 10");
             return;
        }
        else{
             System.out.println("more than or equal to 10");
             return;
        }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestReturn a = new TestReturn();
        int[] ab = {67, 56, 34, 89, 2, 23, 92, 33, 9, 74};
        a.printNum(ab);

    }

}
```

In the above code return has been used twice. While running the code you can see that according to the input the code runs only once . Now if the return statement in the else block is commented out the loop runs for 5 times till it reaches the value 2 and then it stops printing.

This can be achieved through break statement also. Are there any more advantages of this return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only advantage of the return statement is that it exits the method. So if you had any further code after the loop and used `break`, that would be executed.

With `return`, it is not executed.

This is generally how I use `return` - if I know the method has finished executing for the purposes of what you need it for, I put a return statement in.

Answer (score 0):

With `return` you end method's execution. With `break` you get out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is slightly faster than `break` because it doesn't 'get out' of the for-loop, but quits the method completely. Also, if you had code after the loop, it would be run using `break`, but not using `return`.